# Pytorch DataLoader fails when the number of examples are not exactly divided by the batch size

Tags: pytorch

I have coded a custom data loader class in the pytorch. But it fails when iterating through all the number of batches inside an epoch. For example, think I have 100 data examples and my batch size is 9. It will fail in the 10th iteration saying batch size is different which will give a batch size 1 instead of 10. I have put my custom data loader in below.  Also I have put how I extract the data from the loader inside the for-loop.

```py
class FlatDirectoryAudioDataset(tdata.Dataset): #customized dataloader

    def __init__(self, data_dir, transform=None):
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.files = self.__setup_files()

    def __len__(self):
        """
        compute the length of the dataset
        :return: len => length of dataset
        """
        return len(self.files)

    def __setup_files(self):

        file_names = os.listdir(self.data_dir)
        files = []  # initialize to empty list

        for file_name in file_names:

            possible_file = os.path.join(self.data_dir, file_name)
            if os.path.isfile(possible_file) and (file_name.lower().endswith('.wav') or file_name.lower().endswith('.mp3')): #&& (possible_file.lower().endswith('.wav') or possible_file.lower().endswith('.mp3')):
                files.append(possible_file)

        # return the files list
        return files


    def __getitem__ (self,index):
        sample, _ = librosa.load(self.files[index], 16000)

        if self.transform:
            sample=self.transform(sample)

        sample = torch.from_numpy(sample)    
        return sample


from torch.utils.data import DataLoader 

    my_dataset=FlatDirectoryAudioDataset(source_directory,source_folder,source_label,transform = None,label=True)

dataloader_my = DataLoader(
        my_dataset,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_workers=0,
        shuffle=True)


for (i,batch) in enumerate(dataloader_my,0):  
       print(i)
       if batch.shape[0]!=16:
          print(batch.shape)
          assert batch.shape[0]==16,"Something wrong with the batch size"
```

Comment: You're just iterating over your files one at a time. Your 'batch' contains the `sample` value from __getitem__.

Comment: I don't see any `DataLoader` (only `Dataset`). Your code contains an assert to do what you described. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Berriel I have edited the code.

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana you added broken code and did not answer my question.

Comment: Checking batch example on https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html?highlight=dataloader#torch.utils.data.DataLoader the for loop does `for  batch_ndx, sample in enumerate(loader):` so you get a sample. Try to print `type(batch)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use drop_last=True utils.DataLoader(dataset,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle = True,drop_last=True)

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html

Comment: Is there any way use // to divide.

Answer (score 9):

#### Short answer

Set `drop_last=True` to drop the [last incomplete batch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/dataloader.html)

#### Long answer

Based on your code making a reduced version of your Dataloader there is no error for batch sizes.

Using 9 as `batch_size` and having 100 items the last batch just has one item. Running the code below it produces.

Setting drop_last=False the last line is printed and the 'exception' is printed.

```
0 <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([9, 1])
1 <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([9, 1])
2 <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([9, 1])
3 <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([9, 1])
4 <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([9, 1])
5 <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([9, 1])
6 <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([9, 1])
7 <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([9, 1])
8 <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([9, 1])
9 <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([9, 1])
10 <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([9, 1])
# depends on drop_last=True|False
11 <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([1, 1])
Different batch size (last batch) torch.Size([1, 1])
```

So the batch produces good enough batch items to make it to 100 in total

```py
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import os
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.utils.data.dataset as tdata


class FlatDirectoryAudioDataset(tdata.Dataset):  # customized dataloader

    def __init__(self):
        self.files = self.__setup_files()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.files)

    def __setup_files(self):
        return np.array(range(100))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        file = self.files[index]
        sample = np.array([file])
        sample = torch.from_numpy(sample)
        return sample


data = FlatDirectoryAudioDataset()

my_dataset = FlatDirectoryAudioDataset()

batch_size = 9

dataloader_my = DataLoader(
    my_dataset,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    num_workers=0,
    shuffle=True,
    drop_last=True)

for i, sample in enumerate(dataloader_my, 0):
    print(i, print(type(sample), sample.shape)
    if sample.shape[0] != batch_size:
        print("Different batch size (last batch)", sample.shape)
```

Comment: Exactly this is what is happening. So in the last batch during in an epoch contain a different size of a single example.  To keep the same batch size what should I do? I

Comment: You cannot unless length / batch_size has a remainder of 0. Or let __init__ restrict on a batch size length or __getItem__ return dummy items.

I'm not sure why you want to have it like that. What is wrong with this?

Can you mark my answer as the answer :-)

Comment: Well, I found a way. You have to set the drop_last=True  in the Dataloader class. Edit the answer. Then I will mark you as the correct.

Comment: :-) drop_last drops the last batch. I'm still curious about your need to drop the last batch ;-p

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana you can also use make a bit of change in your forward method of model and replace all the instances of BATCH_SIZE with x.shape[0] (considering batch_first = True and `x` is the input ). By doing this we are making out model dependent on a batch size of input rather than a fixed `Batch Size` we defined in the data loader.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a library called [nonechucks](https://github.com/nonechucks) to do exactly this (in case your batch size is falling short not because of being unable to exactly divide but bad samples existing). It lets you deal with bad samples in your dataset dynamically (including automatically fixing the batch size). You can simply wrap your existing PyTorch `Dataset` around with a `SafeDataset` as follows:

```py
bad_dataset = Dataset(...)

import nonechucks as nc
dataset = nc.SafeDataset(bad_dataset)
```